Why does `process.stdout.write` sometimes split lines in `pm2 log` output and how can I ensure atomic output?
I use process.stdout.write in the output of the program so that the output is in one line.
See this example:
while(true) {
  process.stdout.write("X");
  process.stdout.write("Y");
  console.log("");
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

I try to see the output with pm2 log. I expect XY to fall together in a line. But in practice, sometimes Y appears in the next line:
# pm2 log app
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | X
60|app  | Y
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | X
60|app  | Y
60|app  | X
60|app  | Y
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY
60|app  | XY

But they are saved correctly in the log file:
# tailf -f /root/.pm2/logs/app-out.log
XY
XY
XY
XY
XY
XY
XY

In the next example, I add a very short pause of 1ms:
while(true) {
  process.stdout.write("X");
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1)); //added this line
  process.stdout.write("Y");
  console.log("");
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
}

You can see that the output is permanently spaced between X and Y, which makes the problem worse:
# pm2 log app
60|app  | X
60|app  | Y
60|app  | X
60|app  | Y
60|app  | X
60|app  | Y
60|app  | X
60|app  | Y

How can I always be sure in the pm2 log command that the output logs are used wherever process.stdout.write is used and that it doesn't appear until \n or console.log is reached on the next line. Just like what is saved in the file and I can see it with the tail -f command?

If you want to write XY to stdout, why dont you use process.stdout.write("XY\r\n"). Writing a single byte seems unconventional.

@Marc Because I want to do another operation between X and Y and in one line. For example, instead of XY, suppose something like this: checking... success.

If you want to build a cli interface, then you should use the readline module and work with cursors. If you just want to print the output on stdout, then you have to deal with whatever pm2 does if the output is correct written to the logfile/file system.
